# Invoke async IIFEs, synchronously

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

I have several IIFEs that I would like to invoke in a particular order:

Let's say I have the following IIFEs:

```
let foo1 = (async() => {
  await console.log('A')
  await console.log('B')
  await console.log('C')
})();

let foo2 = (async() => {
  await console.log('D')
  await console.log('E')
  await console.log('F')
})();

let foo3 = (async() => {
  await console.log('G')
  await console.log('H')
  await console.log('I')
})();
```

And I would like to invoke them like so:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

...so that I may get the following output:

```
A B C D E F G H I
```

However, the output I actually get is:

```
A D G B E H C F I
```

I am not sure why this is, but I suspect it is because each time the await resolves a promise, it calls in next function in the stack.  How would I invoke them so that they execute synchronously and I get the desired output?

Comment: One way: remove `async` and `await`.

Comment: So basically, just regular synchronous JavaScript.

Comment: Why are they IIFEs to begin with? The first "I" stands for immediate, so there's no way for it to stay an IIFE and have it wait, unless you move the IIFE inside the previous IIFE after the other `await`s.

Comment: They need to be IIFEs as they represent functions within an actual test suite...I don't want to bore you with the details...

Comment: Either put all the `await` in one IIAFE, or declare them as functions and use traditional `foo1().then(foo2).then(foo3)` (or an IIAFE with `await foo1(); await foo2(); await foo3()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to execute them synchronously. You want to execute them asynchronously in order. For that you have to `await` one call before you do the next:

```
(async function() {
  let foo1 = await (async() => {
    //...
  })();

  let foo2 = await (async() => {
    //...
  })();

  let foo3 = await (async() => {
   //...
  })();
})();
```

It doesn't make much sense to `await` on `console.log` though, it also makes little sense to use multiple AIIFEs here then at all, you just need one.

> I suspect it is because each time the await resolves a promise, it calls in next function in the stack.

It's a queue, but basically yes. Using `await` will always cause the expression that is awaited on to be wrapped into a Promise, and Promises always resolve asynchronously. Therefore the execution of the async function halts, and the next function continuation gets dequeued from the event queue and gets executed.

Comment: @dimitri you are missing the `await`s

Comment: I have posted a working demo of this solution here : https://codesandbox.io/s/5z6zjwq3m4

Comment: @Jonas, those functions are just examples, in reality each of them is a functional test suite that I need executed, as you said 'asynchronously in order'.  I will test your solution soon but I think it works...you're a genius!